# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' after downgrading from 4.5 to 4.0 with EF5

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I recently developed a .net 4.5 library using Entity Framework 5. Everything worked fine until I've been told I had to downgrade to .net 4.0 in order to remain compatible with Windows 2003.

I uninstall EF 5 using the Package Manager Console and had the successfull message, then this one:

```
Failed to generate binding redirects for 'MyProjectName'. An item with the same key has already been added.
```

The same message appears after downgrading and installation of Entity Framework.

Everything compile. But on execution I've this exception:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,     
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's   
manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80131040)":"EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

In the Web.Config (and App.Config of the libraries) I have those lines:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
...
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"
                      culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have added a reference in your project for entity framework remove and re-add the reference to the new dll and rebuild

Comment: I did, but i didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved the problem thanks to another topic: [could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749175/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0)

Despite I installed EF 5 package with the Package Manager Console. The actual version of Entity Framework for .Net 4.0 is version 4.4. I've changed the value in config files and it worked!

```
<section name="entityFramework"
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework,
    Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
...
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"
    culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: And the other part of the issue was entity framework 4.0 is shipped with .net and 5.0 was decoupled from .net and available as a nuget package

Comment: in case anyone is digging around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168035/entity-framework-5-0-minimum-net-framework-version-required-net-4-0-or-4-5

Comment: And if you specifically ask package manager to install EF 4.4, it tells you that this version doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nuget to uninstall EF then add it again, Clean and rebuild your project.