# Running EF 5 on server having only .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to deploy EF 5.0 app on a server which has only .NET 4.0 installed.

My project builds and runs successfully on local because I have .NET 4.5 along with .NET 4.0

However on server I have only .NET 4.0 installled, 
when I deploy my app I get following error:

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'.
```

[image]

When I checked references of EF I see that it is referring to the `EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll` instead the .net 4.0 version,
When I add reference to the `EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll` I get following runtime error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

**Help**

REF: [Entity Framework 5.0 - minimum .Net Framework version required ? .Net 4.0 or 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168035/entity-framework-5-0-minimum-net-framework-version-required-net-4-0-or-4-5/12168078#comment87362547_12168078)

Comment: The supported baseline of Microsoft is already .NET Framework 4.5.2 so you really should consider an upgrade.

Comment: according to question referenced above it works with .net 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't found any solution so I downgraded EF version to `4.1` and it worked.

Manually removed EF references in `packages.config`,
Deleted reference to the `EntityFramework.dll`

and then using package manager console installed EF 4.1

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10715.0
```

Comment: Why do you want to run old, unsupported, versions of .NET and EF?

Comment: Because I do not own the server and .NET 4.0 is installed there so allowed to develop using only .NET 4